# How to connect to the WSO2 AM database thorugh client?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am newbie to WSO2 AM and researching to understand it's good features. It seems that "The default database of user manager is the H2 database that comes with WSO2 products. We can configure it to point to databases by other vendors such as IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL using the scripts provided by WSO2 for installing and configuring relational databases".

- How we can connect WSO2 AM to MySQL DB? What files needs to be
  changed? (I'm interested to use MySQL and not H2 db)
- How we can use external client to see all tables?

Requesting you to please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following sample works better with a fresh install(prior to initial start-up) :

1. Put the Mysql jar connector/driver in wso2am/repository/components/lib directory.
2. MySql you will need 2 databases :

> ```
> mysql> create database reg_db;
>
> mysql> create database am_db;
>
> mysql> grant all on reg_db.* to dba@localhost identified by 'dba';
>
> mysql> grant all on am_db.* to dba@localhost identified by 'dba';
>
> mysql> flush privileges;
> ```

3. Overwrite the following 2 data sources in wso2am/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml

   ```
   <datasource>
       <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
       <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
       <jndiConfig>
           <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
       </jndiConfig>
       <definition type="RDBMS">
         <configuration>  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reg_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
           <username>dba</username>
           <password>dba</password>
           <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
           <maxActive>50</maxActive>
           <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
           <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
           <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
           <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
           <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
       </configuration>
       </definition>
   </datasource>

    <datasource>
           <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
           <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
           <jndiConfig>
               <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
           </jndiConfig>
           <definition type="RDBMS">
              <configuration>  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/am_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
               <username>dba</username>
               <password>dba</password>
               <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
               <maxActive>50</maxActive>
               <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
               <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
               <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
               <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
               <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
           </configuration>
           </definition>
       </datasource>
   ```
4. Start the server with wso2server.sh -Dsetup or wso2server.bat -Dsetup